# ng-transclude showing element twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

Why does this `transcluded` directive repeat ***`Name inside directive = Frank`*** twice?

I thought I understood transclusion but this has me confused.

[*Here's a fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/qdfebjrL/1/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <my-directive>Name in outer controller scope = {{name}}<my-directive/>
</div>


var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'George';
});
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,

        template:   '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                    '<span>Name inside directive = {{name}}</span>',

        link: function (scope) {
            scope.name = 'Frank'
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because you didn't close your tag correctly

`</my-directive>` instead of `<my-directive/>`

Comment: (which was duplicating the directive because the browser is trying its best to understand what that means)

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo:

```
<my-directive>Name in outer controller scope = {{name}}</my-directive>
```